# Laravel query - get the best selling item

Tags: laravel, eloquent, sum, max

I'm new to Laravel and I use Laravel 5.1.

I have this table in database:
[image]

This is table for purchased itesm. I want to know what is the best way to calculate the best selling voucher - every purchase has voucher_id ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way of doing it is using one single query for counting and also getting the id of the best seller in the same query:

```
PurchasedItem::select(DB::raw('COUNT(id) as cnt', 'voucher_id'))->groupBy('voucher_id')->orderBy('cnt', 'DESC')->first();
```

Comment: How to get this with $thebest = Auth::user()->sales()->  ... what is next ?

Comment: Try using:
$thebest = Auth::user()->sales()->select(DB::raw('COUNT(id) as cnt', 'voucher_id'))->groupBy('voucher_id')->orderBy('cnt', 'DESC')->first();

Comment: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found

Comment: You have to add:

"use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;"

Just at the top of your file.

Comment: ok works, but any idea how I can build this with eloquent function max() ?

Comment: You cant, max if for getting max value of a column, and not for counting appearances of a value like you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Could Probably do something like this if you want to use eloquent

```
   $Voucher = Sales::sortBy(function ($sale) {
     return $sale->voucher_id->count();
    }, SORT_REGULAR, true)->take(1)->get();
```

Comment: I write:  $thebest = Auth::user()->sales()->sortBy(function ($sale) {
     return $sale->voucher_id->count();
    }, SORT_REGULAR, true)->take(1); but get: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sortBy()

Answer (score 0):

If you want today's best selling item:-

```
Order::whereDate('date','<',date('Y-m-d'))->select('voucher_id', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as `count`'))->groupBy('voucher_id')->orderBy('count', 'DESC')->first();
```

If you want to get top 5 selling items:-

```
Order::select('voucher_id', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as `count`'))->groupBy('voucher_id')->orderBy('count', 'DESC')->limit(5)->get();
```

If you want top 5 selling items between two dates:-

```
Order::whereDate('date','<',date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2023-02-01')))->whereDate('date','>',date('Y-m-d',strtotime('2022-12-31')))->select('voucher_id', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as `count`'))->groupBy('voucher_id')->orderBy('count', 'DESC')->limit(5)->get();
```

Answer (score -2):

I will Try And Success this Code.You Can try to best.

```
<?php      

    $topsales = DB::table('purchase_order_details')
           ->leftJoin('products','products.id','=','purchase_order_details.product_id')
           ->select('products.id','products.name','purchase_order_details.product_id',
                DB::raw('SUM(purchase_order_details.quantity) as total'))
           ->groupBy('products.id','purchase_order_details.product_id','products.name')
           ->orderBy('total','desc')
           ->limit(6)
           ->get();

   ?>
```